# IDEA Глючит

Tags: android-studio, android, intellij-idea

Это только у меня так?
IDEA IntellJ 14.0.2

Нажатие на F2

[image: asd]

Comment: Ну вот не надо этим пользоваться.
Привыкайте делать все в xml

Comment: А что, кто-то GUI мышкой рисует? Какая жесть

Comment: @argamidon, это просто мышка в кадр попала, кстати заметье если мышкой 2 раза нажать на элемент то все норм, если выбрать элемент и нажать F2, то вот такое будет

Comment: Всегда делайте дизайн в XML файле, во-первых, Вы понимаете как все устроено, во-вторых, ГУИ редакторы могут запихнуть лишнего много, либо сделать позиционирование абсолютное, что является неприемлемым для девайсов со множеством различных экранов

Comment: @CROSP, может мне еще на блокноте начать писать?!
Все норм работает, если что-то не понравится, можно переключиться и подправить через xml. Просто порой чтобы искать в коде id Можно упросить себе жизнь и одним нажатием изменить.
Иначе зачем создатели IDEA впихнули сюда только TEXT и ID. Самые важные параметры.
Я тебе про ГЛЮК говорю, а ты мне про то, чтобы xml писать, не хочу я там писать, хочу чтобы не глючила IDEA, вот и создал тему, если не сталкивался с этим. Пиши далше в XML и все.
Чот за сайт такой, один постоянно хамит, другой вообще не по теме пишет.
И каждый раз одни и теже люди.